# Does spectral theory assume separability

Tags: sp.spectral-theory, hilbert-spaces

On an infinite dimensional space, the spectral theorem for compact normal operators says that the eigenvectors form an orthonormal basis which, from wikipedia, is equivalent to the space being seperable. So is the decomposition only valid for seperable spaces?

Thanks

Comment: It is also valid in the non-separable case but in the rather trivial sense that the space splits into a direct sum of two spaces, one on which the operator vanishes and a separable one which is spanned by the eigenvectors.

Answer (score 7):

If $T:H\to H$ is a normal operator, $\operatorname{ker}T=\operatorname{ker}T^*$ (recall that $\|Tx\|^2= (T^*Tx,x)=(T T^*x,x)=\|T^*x\|^2$). So there is a $T$-invariant  orthogonal decomposition $H=\operatorname{ker}T\oplus\overline{T(H)}$. If $T$ is compact, the latter factor is separable.

Comment: (this was meant to be a comment, with too much TeX)